# Core data integer32 vs integer64

Tags: ios, core-data, integer, persistence

I can't actually decide what should be used between these two types in next situation:

I know that certain attribute in my app will have range between 0 - 1000000 and targeted devices can support both 32 and 64 bit architecture.

For storing such a value I need uint32_t  which can have a range between 0 to 4294967295 if I am right? So equivalent in Core Data would be Integer32?

I guess that using Integer64 will not make huge impact on memory consumption in my case, but what is the right choice between these two when targeted devices can have 64bit architecture but stored values are in range of just unsigned int type ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Core Data property's type  does not depend on a device's arch. You choose it based on requirements to your data struct. Define your needs if it is suffice to use `uint32_t` (which equal to `Integer 32`) use it, need more than use `Integer 64`.

So in your case:

> For storing such a value I need uint32_t which can have a range
>   between 0 to 4294967295 if I am right? So equivalent in Core Data
>   would be Integer32?

You can use Core Data's type `Integer 32` safely.